# Destroying main class object

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public void executeRepeat(String s) {
    this.move = s;
    storeValue = move;
    i = Integer.parseInt(move);
    timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            i--;
            if(i <= 0) {
                move = "" + i;
                if (move.trim().equals("0")) {
                    Thread th = new Thread(new DetectImage());
                    th.start();
                }
                timer.stop();
            }
            jTextField1.setText("" + i);
        }
    });
    timer.start();          
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    move = jTextField1.getText();      
    executeRepeat(move);
}

public static int stay = 0;

class DetectImage implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (stay < 3) {
            try {
                stay++;
                // few steps for comparison  
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TrafficMainGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        if (stay >= 3) {
            stay = 0;
            String store = storeValue;
            TrafficMainGUI traffic = new TrafficMainGUI(store);
            traffic.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling `TrafficMainGUI` class from this thread. The whole process is going smoothly.
But I am getting multiple frames opened. I want previous frames to dispose. How should I achieve this here because I cannot access main method for dispose in thread class.

Comment: Either use the same frame always, or use some listener to dispose off the old frames.

Comment: -1. **1.** It seems you could remove some bits from your code example that are irrelevant to this question (to make it easier to understand, which is important since you don't explain your code); and **2.** I believe people on SO deserve reasonably well-formatted code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Frame[] frames = Frame.getFrames();
```

It will give you total frames in the application